# I can't change Django admin login URL

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls, django-login

I will change django login panel URL. I change admin url in urls.py file. URL changed but i can't login.

general urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
        path('testadminlogin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

in settings.py:

```
...


LOGIN_URL = '/testadminlogin/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL ='/testadminlogin/'

...
```

I will login by this URL: "mysite.com/testadminlogin/"

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: It has to be enough to change `urls.py` with `path('<your-new-url>/', admin.site.urls),`. What an error do you get?

Comment: Yes, the URL is changing, but I cannot log in with my username and password from the new address.